# Get absolute path and move file

Tags: android, file, move, absolute-path

I am new to android programming. I am creating an application in which i am supposed to get absolute path of file from Custom Gallery and move that file to private folder. I searched a lot but I am not able to get any perfect answer. Please help me in writing code for it. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get absolute path of your SD CARD:

```
String SDCARD_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/";


File dirFolder = new File(path);

File[] folders = dirFolder.listFiles(); // list of all files and folder into this path
for (File file : folders) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        file.getName() // this will return folder name
    } else {
        file.getName(); // this will return file name with extension
    }
}
```

do the recursive method across the whole process.

Copy file:

```
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(filePath + fileNameWithExtension);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = OUTPUT_PATH + "/" + FILE_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        new File(outFileName).createNewFile();
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }
```

after that just delete the file if you want:

```
String myFile = filePath+"/"+fileNameWithExtension;
if (new File(myFile).delete())
            // do something
        else
            // do something
```